# get keys from MapType column in pyspark and use it in navigation

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark df with following schema:

```
|-- col1 : string
|-- col2 : string
|-- data: struct
|    |-- items: map (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- key: string
|    |    |-- value: struct
|    |    |    |-- id: string 
|    |    |    |-- legalNature
```

and I'm recieving different json with different keys below items object,
here example:

```
+-------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   col1| col2    | data                                                                                                                                                                                   |
+-------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| xxx   |  yyy    |{"data":{"items":{"71f3e2e4-5c3a-466d-8063-7bfd753b303c":{"id":"123","legalNature":"legalNature","allowedSignature":[],"category":"TP01","createdOn":"2021-01-22T13:17:12.502+01:00"}}}}|
| ...   |  ...    |{"data":{"items":{"86c6b41e-085c-eb11-a812-000d3ab29c25":{"id":"153","legalNature":"legalNature","allowedSignature":[],"category":"TP01","createdOn":"2021-01-22T13:17:12.502+01:00"}}}}|
|       |         |{"data":{"items":{"56c6b41e-085c-eb11-a812-000d3ab29c24":{"id":"173","legalNature":"legalNature","allowedSignature":[],"category":"TP01","createdOn":"2021-01-22T13:17:12.502+01:00"}}}}|
|       |         |{"data":{"items":{"1843f179-3687-eb11-a812-0022489bac2c":{"id":"193","legalNature":"legalNature","allowedSignature":[],"category":"TP01","createdOn":"2021-01-22T13:17:12.502+01:00"}}}}|
|       |         |{"data":{"items":{"2643f179-3687-eb11-a812-0022489bac2a":{"id":"133","legalNature":"legalNature","allowedSignature":[],"category":"TP01","createdOn":"2021-01-22T13:17:12.502+01:00"}}}}|
|       |         |{"data":{"items":{"91f3e2e4-5c3a-466d-8063-7bfd753b345i":{"id":"143","legalNature":"legalNature","allowedSignature":[],"category":"TP01","createdOn":"2021-01-22T13:17:12.502+01:00"}}}}|
+-------+---------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Items is a struct of type `MapType(StringType(), itemsSchema)`, since the key string from map type may change in each json I get, how can I navigate my json schema dynamically in order to get fields inside items struct?

For instance I need something like this for performing select operation:

```py
df
    .select(
      col("col1"),
      col("col2").alias("my_col_2"),
      col(f"data.items.{itemsKey}.legalNature"),
      col(f"data.items.{itemsKey}.id"))
)
```

where itemsKey change for each json inside my df.
I already see that for getting key I can use `map_keys` function, like this:

```py
  df.select(map_keys("data.items"))
```

But the problem is that this function is returning a data frame and not a string, more precisley a dataframe with different itemsKey for each row.
Is there a way to get dynamicallymy itemsKey?

I hope I've been clear, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use explode function of spark.sql

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode

df3 = df.select(df.*,explode(df.data.items))
```

This will give results as

```
+-------+-------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
|   col1| key                                       |value                     
+-------+-------------------------------------------+-----+---------------------------------------
|    ...| a04452cb-a909-47b0-ad5a-9bc44c6014e3|brown|{"legalNature":"legalNature","id": "123",..}|
+-------+----+-----+--------------------------------|---------------------------------------------|
```

To filter with your particular itemId, simply use filter function

```
filteredValue = df3.filter(df.key == "Your_item_id").select("value").first();

legalName = filteredValue["value"]["legalName"]
id = filteredValue["value"]["id"]
...
...
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understood, I edited the question to be more clear..

Comment: you said: """filteredValue = df3.filter(df.key == "Your_item_id").select("value").first();"""but  I don't know the "Your_item_id", cause it's different for each json

Comment: Is there a way to get dynamicallymy itemsKey? This is what you asked. This means that you have the item id right? I am not exactly understanding the question

Comment: Yeah I don't have items id and that's why I specified 'dynamically' and 'to use it in navigation'. But with your answer I solved my problem as well, cause actually I don't care to know my itemsId at all, i just needed the value of the struct. In conclusion I did as what u said and added column value directly as further field to use for my navigation. Thanks anyway man!